# How do I script deluge to get information about torrents?

Tags: scripting, bittorrent, deluge

Dealing with a lot of torrents is not always convenient when using GUI. I tried `deluge-console info`, but that didn't give all the info I wanted. So, to make it clear, what I need is a script, that shows how to get information about torrents under control of deluge.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from deluge.log import setupLogger
from deluge.ui.client import client
from twisted.internet import reactor
import argparse
from operator import itemgetter
import pprint

setupLogger()

def on_get_torrents_status(status):
    exclude_labels = args.exclude_labels.split(',') if args.exclude_labels else []
    for data in sorted(status.values(), key=itemgetter('label', 'name')):
        if data['label'] in exclude_labels:
            continue
        plus = '+' if data['is_finished'] else ' '
        label = data['label'].encode('utf8', 'replace')
        name = data['name'].encode('utf8', 'replace')
        size = float(data['total_size']) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
        print '%s [%16s] %6.3f Gb %s' % (plus, label, size, name)
        if args.verbose >= 1:
            save_path = data['save_path'].encode('utf8', 'replace')
            print '    save_path: %s' % save_path
    reactor.stop()

def on_connected(res):
    fields = ['name', 'total_done', 'total_size', 'is_finished', 'hash', 'save_path', 'progress', 'label']
    filter_dict = {'label': args.labels.split(',')} \
        if args.labels \
    else {'label': ['']} \
        if args.labels == '' \
    else None
    client.core.get_torrents_status(filter_dict, fields).addCallback(on_get_torrents_status)

def on_connected_err(res):
    res = res.encode('utf8', 'replace')
    print('Failed to connect to deluge: {}'.format(res))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', '--labels')
parser.add_argument('--exclude-labels')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='count', default=0)
args = parser.parse_args()

d = client.connect()
d.addCallback(on_connected)
d.addErrback(on_connected_err)
reactor.run()
```

Additionally, the script allows to filter by labels. Concerning the information you can get, the list of core fields is returned when no fields are specified (`[]`). More on it [here](https://github.com/deluge-torrent/deluge/blob/deluge-1.3.12/deluge/core/torrent.py#L581-L769). As for plugins, you can search for `register_status_field` calls, like [this one](https://github.com/deluge-torrent/deluge/blob/deluge-1.3.12/deluge/plugins/label/label/core.py#L99).