# Deluge bash script idea, do not start download with x or less peers at start of download, can someone point me in right research direction?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, deluge

Not asking someone to do my work for me I know the golden rule of SO/SE but this shell script would be really helpful to me, basically if a download starts with x or less peers, it stops and deletes torrent and data, usually 2 peers is the number but being able to change it would be nice as well.

I don't know linux or unix and such a script doesn't exist on deluge scripts github.

First off does it seem possible? is it easy and where could I begin to learn to try and make it? linux/unix language is quite broad, I can come back here and ask if I'm on the right track but have no clue how a deluge bash even looks never seen one.

thanks any help.

Comment: If I recall correctly deluge doesn't have a command-line interface that's non-interactive.  Someone else seems to have had a similar problem to yours - have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261854/how-do-i-script-deluge-to-get-information-about-torrents) ...

Comment: thank you much, all of that is way above my knowledge level, I think it would take me a year trying to do it myself, but I think it's the right idea, first good lead I've gotten asking about this script idea, I will ask around with somewhere like freelancer or fiverr and see if I can anybody interested and share all that information to help them, might be able to get it done.